# How to compile my Python software that's in a folder with sub-folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, compilation, python-3.6

So my software is all contained in the `BankingSystem` folder. Within that folder, there are many other folders such as `Account`, `Algorithm`, etc. How can I compile all python files in the `BankingSystem` folder **INCLUDING** the sub-folders?

Here is the directory of `BankingSystem`

```
BankingSystem
│   main.py
│
├───Account
│       account.py
│
├───Algorithms
│       accountAccess.py
│       accountManage.py
│       accountMoney.py
│
├───Database
│       Accounts.json
│
├───Login
│       login.py
│
└───Register
        register.py
```

Comment: what do you mean by *compile*?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga make an .exe file. Or a .pyc file. I've compiled single files before, and I get a .pyc file in a folder called __pycache__. Sorry I might sound stupid, I'm a beginner at Python

Comment: do you *need* an exe? Why? Just running your main script, i.e. `python BankingSystem/main.py` will compile all the files you need. You don't actually need `.pyc` files, the interpreter runtime loads the bytecode into memory on the fly, those are only to cache that process for programs where startup time is essential... again, *what are you trying to accomplish exactly*?

Comment: I'm trying to finalize the software, i guess. I though it would be easier for the user to run a .exe file than have to download Python and then run the main.py file

Comment: Generating `.pyc` files **does not prevent you from having to somehow distribute the python runtime to run your python program** if that is what you are interested in. Again, you really need to be specific about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad, I thought that making a .pyc file would prevent me from having to distribute the python runtime. I'm pretty new to this so I guess I didn't have all my information. I understand that my question was not very precise, but I think you gave me my answer. Thanks again, and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Don't apologise. In any case, likely you want to use something like [pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to distribute your python programs. It handles most common packages and dependancies out there, so it could well do for your use case

Comment: Ok great! I will look at pyinstaller. Thank you very much, have a good one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a .sh file if using Linux, or .bash file if using windows. 
Write the normal steps you use to compile each file and save it as one of the formats above. And run that particular file.